Is there a way to customize the behaviour of code folding in Visual Studio Code?
VSCode supports folding but folder block does not provide much information about the contents. I am wondering if there is a way of customizing how folding works?
I am switching from Vim and struggling with folding since I use this feature a lot.
Eg. when folding - Vim would show the number of folded lines and the contents of the first line in the folded block, which works particularly well when writing unit tests:

The VSCode though does not show any information about the folded block and does not show the first line, which makes it completely opaque. The same looks like this in VSCode which is not nearly as helpful:

Eg. VIM has a setting called folding method (aka foldmethod) where you can set the criteria for the folding (eg. marker, indent, etc). I know that VSCode supports similar modes, like region folding similar to VIM marker folding albeit not as flexible since the marker cannot be customized I believe. Likewise the indentation mode has similar tweaks but sadly that do not control what and how the folded block is displayed Folding manual.
I did some research and could not find a way but wondering if I'm missing something. Is there a way to modify the indentation based folding behavior (eg. to match that of Vim)? Any pointers would be appreciated.

This extension lets you specify folding rules using regex, but I don't think it lets you do summaries.

@HolyBlackCat Thanks for the response and for the recommendation - I'll check it out. I don't have a problem with criteria for folding though and indentation mode works just fine. I guess I'm looking for customizing how the folded block is renderred. I've seen some forum threads where people were asking the same question, but with simpler requirement, like just display the number of folded lines, but I suspect it's just not possible without having to write my own extension. For me - this is a vital feature because we have test cases of 200+ sloc per case, so folding is a must.
